# AWS Javascript SDK with Promises

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, promise, q

I am trying to use AWS Javascript SDK for accessing S3. I am using the Promises with 'Q' library. However it is not working. 
I have set the Q dependency also.

```
var Q = require('q');
AWS.config.setPromisesDependency(Q);
```

Here's the code I have:

```
var listBucketPromise = s3.listBuckets().promise();
listBucketPromise.then(
    function (response) {
        console.log(" response = " + response );
    } ,
    function (error) {
        console.log(" error = " + error);
    }
);
```

This shows on console :

```
response = function (resolve, reject) {
      self.on('complete', function(resp) {
        if (resp.error) {
          reject(resp.error);
        } else {
          // define $response property so that it is not enumberable
          // this prevents circular reference errors when stringifying the JSON object
          resolve(Object.defineProperty(
            resp.data || {},
            '$response',
            {value: resp}
          ));
        }
      });
      self.runTo();
    }
```

I have a valid s3 client set correctly. The callback format works:

```
s3.listBuckets(function (err, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Why is the promise code not working ?

Comment: What do you mean by "*This shows on console*", is that an error message?

Comment: Assuming that `setPromisesDependency` expects a promise constructor, try passing `Q.Promise` instead

Comment: I am testing the script via WebStorm terminal. That's what I meant by console. The code that prints that log is : `console.log(" response = " + response );`

Comment: `AWS.config.setPromisesDependency(Q.Promise);` did  make the difference.. I am able to get the response now.. Many thanks !. If you could post that as an answer, I will be happy to accept it.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a `Promise` constructor to `setPromisesDependency`. The [`Q` function](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qvalue) that you used does not expect a callback, when called with the typical promise executor callback it just returned a promise fulfilled with that function value.

You can use [`Q.Promise`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qpromiseresolver) instead, which also is documented in [this blog post's example](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/developer/support-for-promises-in-the-sdk/):

```
// Use Q implementation of Promise
AWS.config.setPromisesDependency(require('Q').Promise);
```